# jquery image slider fullscreen with multiple images in a screen

Tags: jquery

I have been googling and duckducking and githubing around a fullscreen multiple images mixing slider like http://www.sling.me/ but the closest and better one I can find is http://nicinabox.com/superslides/#download-062.

Can anyone please let us know here if you know any?

Cheerio,
Mark

Comment: u can use supersized.
http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/

Comment: I need it to be able to mix a few images in a screen just like sling.me